Exporting & reimporting particles as alembic replaces meshes with cubes & empties
I'm trying to export a particle animation as an alembic file.
When using the following settings to export it, and then re-importing that file into blender again, some of the meshes are in completely different spots, some are replaced with cubes, others with empties and others are replaced with (what I assume are) animated points.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this to ensure the export is identical to the cached particles?
Here's what the particles look like before exporting:

And here's what they look like after being re-imported:

